# Inorder tree walk not working

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to practice BST tree implementation with python, following is my code,

```
import pdb

class Node():
    def __init__(self, parent=None, key=None):
        self.parent = parent if parent != None else None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key if key != None else None

class BST():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node() 

    def insertKey (self, key):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        # transverse till we find empty position
        if (self.root.key == None):
            self.root.key = key
        else:
            node = self.root
            while (node.left != None and node.right != None):
                if node.key < key:
                    node = node.right
                else:
                    node = node.left
            #we have node either left or right is empty
            if node.key < key:
                node.right = Node (node, key)
            else:
                node.left = Node (node, key)

    def inOrder (self, node):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        if node != None:
            self.inOrder (node.left)
            print node.key
            self.inOrder (node.right)

    def printLeft (self, node):
        if node != None:
            self.printLeft (node)
            print node.key

    def debugAll (self):
        self.inOrder (self.root)
        #self.printLeft (self.root)

    def fromArray (self, numbers):
        srt = sorted(numbers)
        print srt
        length = len(srt)
        mid = length/2
        rootEle = srt[mid]
        self.insertKey (rootEle)
        for i in range (1, mid+1):
            try:
                #pdb.set_trace()
                self.insertKey (srt[mid-i])
                self.insertKey (srt[mid+i])
            except IndexError:
                pass

bst = BST()
bst.fromArray ([1,2,4,3,6,5,10,8,9])
bst.debugAll ()
```

However the result of the inOrder tree walk is unexpected

```
1
4
5
6
10
```

I tried to debug through the pdb while inserting the keys, the keys are properly inserted, but when transversing the tree, some Node are skipped because they're marked as 'NoneType'. May be I am missing out on some language specifics here.

Comment: You are not forming the tree properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, the code you have below isn't right:

```
        while (node.left != None and node.right != None):
            if node.key < key:
                node = node.right
            else:
                node = node.left
```

It will stop descending if *either* the left or the right node doesn't exist.

EDIT:  If you modify the loop like this, it works.  Could be better optimized, but it's a start...

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, parent=None, key=None):
        self.parent = parent if parent != None else None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key if key != None else None

class BST():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def insertKey (self, key):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        # transverse till we find empty position
        if (self.root.key == None):
            self.root.key = key
        else:
            node = self.root
            while 1:
                if node.key < key:
                    if node.right is None:
                        node.right = Node(node, key)
                        break
                    else:
                        node = node.right
                else:
                    if node.left is None:
                        node.left = Node(node, key)
                        break
                    else:
                        node = node.left

    def inOrder (self, node):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        if node != None:
            self.inOrder (node.left)
            print node.key
            self.inOrder (node.right)

    def printLeft (self, node):
        if node != None:
            self.printLeft (node)
            print node.key

    def debugAll (self):
        self.inOrder (self.root)
        #self.printLeft (self.root)

    def fromArray (self, numbers):
        srt = sorted(numbers)
        print srt
        length = len(srt)
        mid = length/2
        rootEle = srt[mid]
        self.insertKey (rootEle)
        for i in range (1, mid+1):
            try:
                #pdb.set_trace()
                self.insertKey (srt[mid-i])
                self.insertKey (srt[mid+i])
            except IndexError:
                pass

bst = BST()
bst.fromArray ([1,2,4,3,6,5,10,8,9])
bst.debugAll ()
```

Comment: Yes, because it's suppose to find a node, where either of left or right node is non-existent, then after that, we place the key in a newly created Node, accordingly left or right.

Comment: But if you find a node where the right node is non-existent, but you want to put something in the left node, what happens?

Comment: @user1064504 -- I updated the answer and it works, at least for this case.  Two possible optimizations come to mind immediately -- the first is that you don't need a separate tree and node class (each node is the start of a tree), and the second is that if you store left/right as a single child array with two values, then you can set `index = node.key < key` and then use node.child[index] and cut out half the code in the loop.  Have fun!

Comment: Also, the pattern in `self.parent = parent if parent != None else None` is indeed idiomatic, but completely unnecessary if you're going to store None anyway.  Just use `self.parent =  None`.  And it is idiomatic (and cheaper) to check for `is None` rather than `== None`.  This works because None is a singleton -- there can be only one (None).